# Using pip to install dev pyinstaller (2.2) from github

Tags: python-2.7, debian, pip, pyinstaller

I am trying to install the development version of PyInstaller (2.2). I tried

`sudo pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller`

but this does not work. I need it because it fixes some problems with imports that I am trying to use it for.

Comment: That is fairly easy to google. The correct command is `pip install git+https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller.git` .

Comment: I was missing the stupid .git on the end. A lot of examples that I did google had tar.gz on the end and there was no tar.gz in this repo. I had tried it with the git+ at the beginning with no luck as well. Thanks